# KeyboardAvoidingView is working in ios devices/simulator in Expo project

Tags: ios, react-native, keyboard, flatlist

I am trying to use KeyboardAvoidingView to show the TextInput to the user whenever user type any data. I have used different combination of KeyboardAvoidingView and i have implemented it in different places(like before & after LinearGradient, after Imagebackground, in headerComponent etc.,). I have also moved scrollview to different places in the code.   Keyboard is still hiding the TextInput. It is not pushing screen upwards. I have referred different posts in the portal and tried. None of them are working in IOS simulator(and iPhone device). I have also tried KeyboardAwareScrollView. Everything is working in Andriod simulator only. Any suggestion on how to fix this?. Please let me know for any questions.

````
const headerComponent = () => (
          
    <View >
        <Text style={styles.spcl}></Text>
        <CalendarStrip
                    calendarAnimation={{type: 'sequence', duration: 30}}
                    daySelectionAnimation={{type: 'border', duration: 200, borderWidth: 1, borderHighlightColor: '#708090'}}
                    style={{height: 100, paddingTop: 20, paddingBottom: 10,borderRadius:10}}
                    calendarHeaderStyle={{color: '#800000'}}
                    calendarColor={'#778899'}
                    dateNumberStyle={{color: '#800000'}}
                    minDate={minDate}
                    maxDate={maxDate}
                    selectedDate={selCalDate}
                    dateNameStyle={{color: '#800000'}}
                    highlightDateNumberStyle={{color: '#eee8aa'}}
                    highlightDateNameStyle={{color: '#eee8aa'}}
                    disabledDateNameStyle={{color: 'grey'}}
                    disabledDateNumberStyle={{color: 'grey'}}
                    //datesBlacklist={blockData}
                    // datesWhitelist={datesWhitelist}
                    // datesBlacklist={datesBlacklist}
                    // iconLeft={require('./img/left-arrow.png')}
                    // iconRight={require('./img/right-arrow.png')}
                    // onPress={(date)=>{alert(date)}}
                    iconContainer={{flex: 0.1}}
                    onDateSelected={e => {
                      setselCalDate(e);
                      let d = moment(e._d).format('YYYY-MM-DD');
                    //console.log(d);
                    //console.log(selCalDate);
                      
                      setselectedDate(d);
                      
                    }}
          />
      </View>
      
  )
  const footerComponent = () => (
    <View>
     <Text style={styles.heading}>Patient Name</Text>
        <TextInput
                placeholder='Patient name'
                style={styles.nameInput}
                onChangeText={(val)=>n = val}
                onEndEditing={()=>setPatient(n)}
                defaultValue={Patient}
            />
            <Text style={styles.heading}>Age</Text>
            <TextInput 
              style={styles.nameInput}
              keyboardType = 'number-pad'
              onChangeText = {(num)=> a=num}
              onEndEditing={()=>setAge(a)}
              defaultValue={Age}
              
            />
        <Text style={styles.heading}>Select Gender</Text>
        <View style={styles.genderView}>
        <RadioButtonGroup
            containerStyle={{ marginBottom: 10,flexDirection:'row' }}
            selected={current}
            onSelected={(value) => setCurrent(value)}
            containerOptionStyle={{margin:15}}
            radioBackground="green"
          >
            <RadioButtonItem value="M" label="Male" />
            <RadioButtonItem
              value="F"
              label={
                <Text style={{ color: "red" }}>Female</Text>
              }
            />
          </RadioButtonGroup>
          
        </View>
        <Text style={styles.heading}>Problem</Text>
        <TextInput 
          editable
          multiline
          numberOfLines={4}
          maxLength={100}
          style={styles.nameInput2} placeholder={'Optional'} 
          // onChangeText={text => setReason(text)}
          onChangeText={(val)=>p = val}
          onEndEditing={()=>setReason(p)}
          defaultValue={Reason}
        />
      <View style={styles.btnView}>
          <CommonBtn
            w={300}
            h={45}
            backgroundColor={'green'}
            txt={'Book Now'}
            status={true}
            onClick={() => {
              if (addNewBooking()) {
                router.push('Success');
              } 
              
            }}
          />
        </View>
   </View>
    
  )
  return (
    <KeyboardAvoidingView
    keyboardVerticalOffset={height}
    behavior="padding"
    style={{ flex: 1 }}
    enabled>
          <LinearGradient
        colors={Colors.LINEAR_1}
        style={{flex:1}}
        start={{ x: 0, y: 0 }}
        end={{ x: 1, y: 1 }}
      >
           <ImageBackground source={require('../assets/images/Dental2.jpeg')}
            imageStyle={{ flex: 1 }}
            backgroundColor={'blue'}
            resizeMode='cover'
            style={{ flex: 1, width: undefined, height: Platform.OS === 'ios' ? 170 : 150, }}
            >
                <ScrollView>
               <View style={{marginTop: 0,marginBottom:'2%',  alignItems: 'center'}}>
              <Text style={{fontSize:45,marginBottom:'2%',marginTop:'10%', fontWeight:'900',color:'#00008b',fontFamily:'Oswald_600SemiBold'}} numberOfLines={1}>
                      Den
                      <Text style={{color: '#3cb371'}}>
                      Health
                      </Text>
                      <Image
                        source={require('../assets/images/dental-icon.png')}
                        style={{width: 40,
                          height: 40,
                          margin: 5,
                          resizeMode: 'contain',}}
                      />
                    </Text>
               </View> 
               <View style={styles.spcl}>
               
          <FlatList
                    nestedScrollEnabled
                    numColumns={4}
                    data={slots}
                    renderItem={
                      ({item,index}) => {
                      return(
                      <TouchableOpacity
                      disabled={item.selected}
                      onPress={() => {
                        //alert(item.id +':'+ item.selected + ':' +index);
                        if (item.id == index + 1 && !item.selected) {
                          if (Object.getOwnPropertyNames(user.CAppoint).length >3) {
                            alert('oops!. You have three existing appointments already.');
                          }
                          else if (selectedDate == null || selCalDate == '') {
                            alert('Please select the date');
                          }
                          else
                          {
                              setSelectedSlot(index)
                          };
                        }
                        else {
                          alert('oops! This slot is unavailable');
                        }
                        
                      }}
                      >
                        <LinearGradient
                          colors={item.id==selectedSlot+1?CHOSEN:item.selected?BOOKED:AVAILABLE}
                          style={{
                            width: 85,
                            height: 25,
                            margin:5,
                            justifyContent: 'center',
                            alignItems: 'center',
                            borderRadius: 10,
                            opacity: 0.75,
                          }}
                          >
                          <Text style={{color: '#fff', fontSize: 14}}>{item.sloT}</Text>
                        </LinearGradient>
                          </TouchableOpacity>
                      )
                    }
                  }
                    keyExtractor={item => item.id}
                    ListHeaderComponent={headerComponent}
                    ListFooterComponent={footerComponent}
          />
          
               </View>
               </ScrollView>
           </ImageBackground>
           
           </LinearGradient>
          
    </KeyboardAvoidingView>
    
  );```
````